# git: remove the unwanted file from remote already pushed to feature-branch

Tags: git

I accidentally pushed one unwanted file to my remote feature branch.

There is this `documentation/~$screenshots.pptx` file which might be the temp file system generated automatically while I opened the doc and did not close.

After I generate a PR, I found this file was pushed too.

Tried to use  `git rm documentation/~$screenshots.pptx`   but got this error:

```
fatal: pathspec './documentation/~.pptx' did not match any files
```

Since I was my last commit, so I used `git reset --soft HEAD^` now.
Checked the `git status`: `documentation/~$screenshots.pptx` is listed as `new file:   documentation/~$screenshots.pptx`.

Tried `git rm  documentation/~$screenshots.pptx` still got `fatal: pathspec './documentation/~.pptx' did not match any files` error.

How could I get rid of this file from my PR?

Comment: Your shell expanded `$screenshots` to the empty string because your shell variable `screenshots` is not set. Protect against expansion!

Comment: try with `git rm  documentation/'~$'screenshots.pptx`

Comment: Screen shell metacharatcter `$` with backslash: `\$`

Comment: Tried git rm documentation/'~$'screenshots.pptx ,  git rm 'documentation/~$screenshots.pptx' , git rm documentation/~\$screenshots.pptx, git rm documentation/\~\$screenshots.pptx  all not working.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is listed as "new file:", that means it is in the index, ready to be committed.

In that case, the command to use would be:

```
git rm --cached 'documentation/~\$screenshots.pptx'
```

(try different syntax, but the point remains: you need to use the [`--cached` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached))

Then commit and push to update your PR.